# Fail in assigning self.delegate it produce unrecognized selector sent

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols, flip

I'm a new in iOS, and I have trouble in implementing *@protocol* so sorry if you think this is an easy thing..

i've been searching around stackoverflow.com, the webs and also try uncle Google for a while and I decided to ask here...

The main idea is calling a MyViewController from TopViewController and do flip animation 
I Start with creating the protocols..

```
    // This is my Delegate header
    // MyViewController.h

    @protocol MyViewControllerlDelegate

    - (void) myViewControllerDidFinish;

    @end

    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController 
    {
     id <MyViewControllerlDelegate> delegate;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyViewControllerlDelegate> delegate;

    - (IBAction) done;

    @end
```

and below is on implementation :

```
    // MyViewController.m

    #import "MyViewController.h"

    @implementation MyViewController

    @synthesize delegate;

    // Another Code above

    - (IBAction)done 
    {
     [self.delegate myViewControllerDidFinish];
    }

    // Another Code Below

    @end
```

I use above object to be called from another view below and add flip transition in it :

```
// TopViewController.h

#import "MyViewController.h"

@class MapScrollView;

@interface TopViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate,MyViewControllerlDelegate> 
{
    UIScrollView *topScrollView;
    UIButton *infoButton;
}

@end
```

TopViewController.h Implementation
    //TopViewController.m

```
#import "TopViewController.h"
#import "CustomScrollView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)loadView 
{    
    // Step 1: make the outer paging scroll view
    CGRect topScrollViewRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    topScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:topScrollViewRect];
    topScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    topScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    topScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    topScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    topScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(topScrollViewRecte.size.width,
                                              topScrollViewRecte.size.height);
    topScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.view = pagingScrollView;

    CustomScrollView *sView = [[[MapScrollView alloc] init] autorelease];

    sView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    [sView displayTiledMap];

    [pagingScrollView addSubview:sView];

    // add Info Button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(infoIsTouch:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(282.0, 440.0, 18.0, 19.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)infoIsTouch:(id)sender
{
 MyViewController *myView = 
 [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 myView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        //
        //Here where the code is crash 
        //
 [myView setDelegate:self];
        //
        //Code from here to below is not run...
        //
 [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
 [myView release];
}

- (void) myViewControllerDidFinish
{
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

etc... 

@end
```

Below code produce following compiler error..

```
2010-12-06 01:09:07.946 MyViewDelegatePractice[9473:207] -[TopViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f30fb0
2010-12-06 01:09:07.949 MyViewDelegatePractice[9473:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TopViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f30fb0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    // Cuts... 
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Those error is raised when i press infoButton which call -(void)infoIsTouch:(id)sender method, then stop at [myView setDelegate:self] line.. could anyone give me a hint where is my mistakes is ?

NOTE : If you disgust with my english.. fell free to comment abut that also.. but before that.. i'm sorry i've try my best..

Comment: `MyViewControllerlDelegate` and `FanglesMapSettingViewControllerDelegate`, which one is it supposed to implement? I'm confused.

Comment: @sam-ritchie - thanks sam, it's my typo.. i forgot to change the variables.. sorry bout that..

Comment: i've change FanglesMapSettingViewControllerDelegate to MyViewControllerlDelegate but still produce same error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have some other variable named `myView` here, that's intercepting your call to the `MyViewController` instance you've just created. Try changing the name of that instance, and see what happens.

Other stuff: ooks like you have a typo in your implementation of `MyViewController`. Change this line:

```
@implementation FanglesMapSettingsViewController
```

to this:

```
@implementation MyViewController
```

And you should be good to go. (You're getting that error because the header file doesn't correspond to any implementation, due to the typo, so you never get the benefit of your `@synthesize delegate;` call.

Also, make sure you declare the proper protocol in `TopViewController`:

```
@interface TopViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, MyViewControllerlDelegate>
```

And change your protocol declaration to:

```
@protocol MyViewControllerlDelegate<NSObject>
```

Other than that, things are looking good.

Comment: @sam-ritchie - thanks sam, it's my typo.. i forgot to change the variables.. sorry about that..

Comment: @sam-ritchie - still error, i actualy modified the codes before i submited.. and it still produce an error..

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense;  `@implementation SomeClass<NSObject>` is pretty much never *ever* the right answer when implementing a class.  If you need `NSObject` like behavior, subclass NSObject!

Comment: Sorry about that, this is a typo. I meant to add that to his protocol declaration. I'll change that right now.

Comment: OK -- that is much better. :)  Still, I don't think it is the actual problem here.   But... useful nonetheless!

Comment: Yes, this was my mistake -- see the above comments. You don't have some other variable named myView, do you?

Comment: Yes.. thats also my typo.. sorry again.. i've check the myViewControllerDidFinish method is not even called, because there an error before  myViewControllerDidFinish mothod is called..

Comment: just updated my answer, suggesting that you rename myView. If you have two objects with that name, you're going to have issues.

Comment: @sam : "Yes, this was my mistake -- see the above comment" sorry sam.. i answer before the comment is appear.. it's my first time in StackOverflow.. :)

Comment: @sam : oh i though what you mean is myViewControllerDidFinish method, nope i dont have any other myView variable..

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line, and hold your mouse over the myView object. Does it have a "delegate" property? Also, try overriding the init method inside MyViewController, and replacing it with initWithDelegate:(id)delegate. Then, you can initialize it with a delegate, and skip this whole mess.

Comment: @sam : sam, when you upgrade the XCode or iOS SDK, do you always restart you mac ?, because don't know why.. it works now.. and you were right.. theres a "delegate" in popup view on XCode just like Visual Studio.. I don't know that... Thank you sam..

Comment: Haha, if it fixed a problem for me once, I would probably restart forever afterward. Congratulations!

Comment: Haha.. I feel so stupid.. all i need to do is restart it.. thanks for the tips. *btw 4.2 called GM release.. is it final release ?

Comment: Yeah, you can go to apple's site and download the final version, but GM is equivalent to final.

Comment: Good abstract debugging of that one, Sam!

Comment: Thanks! I have a nagging feeling that if a simple "try cleaning the project" might have been a better lesson for ferry than my back and forth...

Answer (score 8):

Old post, but for anyone else with the same issue make sure you set the Class in the identity inspector to the correct Class.  That was my issue. Probably the most forgotten thing to do in Xcode.

Comment: *this* ... thank you very much, so finicky storyboards are :)

Comment: In my case, I mistakenly made the class that the segue was coming from as the same class as the destination

Answer (score 3):

Do you `@synthesize delegate;` somewhere?  Oh, there it is.  Derp.

OK -- so -- this is a runtime error.   Compiler warnings, etc, be damned (I mean -- fix 'em, definitely, but the compiler is generating code that is running and crashing).

An unrecognized selector means that an attempt was made to invoke a method on an object where that object doesn't respond to said method.   In this case, the backtrace isn't likely to be terribly useful;  you already identified the crash location and why it is crashing.

Try setting a breakpoint on the line that is crashing and then use the debugger to interrogate said object;

```
po object
po (id) [object class]
p (BOOL) [object respondsToSelector: @selector(setDelegate:)]
```

... etc ...

There is something likely terribly obvious going on, but I don't see it offhand.

Comment: Looks like he included @synthesize delegate; in MyViewController.m.

Comment: I think he must have some other variable named myView. The code looks okay, certainly not poor in a way that would produce this error...