# Setting delegate causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, delegates

I'm calling an NSObject from a UIViewController, and I'm setting the view controller as the delegate of the NSObject.

When this code is executed, the app completely crashes on the **simulator** due to **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** (how does that apply here?). When the app runs on a **real device**, the app crashes the third time the code is executed. The output of the real device log is below:

```
(First time)
2012-04-01 13:29:05.154 The Record[19044:707] Done

----
(Second time)
2012-04-01 13:29:06.274 The Record[19044:707] Done

----
(Third time)
2012-04-01 13:29:07.772 The Record[19044:707] -[ViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde2e6e0
2012-04-01 13:29:07.773 The Record[19044:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde2e6e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3211088f 0x37515259 0x32113a9b 0x32112915 0x3206d650 0x537f7 0x4f82b 0x3206a3fd 0x379eafaf 0x37ab076b 0x3206a3fd 0x379eafaf 0x379eaf6b 0x379eaf49 0x379eacb9 0x379eb5f1 0x379e9ad3 0x379e94c1 0x379cf83d 0x379cf0e3 0x3144322b 0x320e4523 0x320e44c5 0x320e3313 0x320664a5 0x3206636d 0x31442439 0x379fde7d 0x4dd8d 0x4dd38)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

I'm just calling the NSObject and setting the view controller as the delegate.

```
Authorization *authorization = [[Authorization alloc] init];
authorization.delegate = self;
```

**When I take out `authorization.delegate = self;` the app does not crash, but I obviously need that line.**

**Edit**: Here is the code. I'm using `@protocol`. Authorization.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "KeychainItemWrapper.h>

@protocol AuthorizationDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)done:(BOOL *)done downloadURL:(NSURL *)downloadURL username:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password reason:(NSString *)reason;
@end

@interface Authorization : NSObject {

    id<AuthorizationDelegate> delegate;
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain;

}

-(id)init;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<AuthorizationDelegate> delegate;

@end

----
//Authorization.m

#import "Authorization.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@implementation Authorization

@synthesize delegate;

-(id)init {

    keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"exampleID" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *passPhrase = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];


    // Start request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.website.com/authorization.php"]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:passPhrase forKey:@"passphrase"];
    [request setPostValue:@"YES" forKey:@"receivingAuthorization"];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

    if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {

        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
        NSString *downloadString = [responseDict objectForKey:@"downloadURL"];
        NSString *username = [responseDict objectForKey:@"username"];
        NSString *password = [responseDict objectForKey:@"password"];

        if ((downloadString != nil) && (username != nil) && (password != nil)) {

            NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:downloadString];

            [delegate done:YES downloadURL:downloadURL username:username password:password reason:@"Received Authorization"];

         } else {

            [delegate done:NO downloadURL:nil username:nil password:nil reason:@"Invalid Request"];

        }

    } else if (request.responseStatusCode == 400) {

        if ([[request responseString] compare:@"Invalid passphrase"] == 0) {

            [delegate done:NO downloadURL:nil username:nil password:nil reason:@"Incorrect Credentials"];

        } else if ([[request responseString] compare:@"Invalid request"] == 0) {

            [delegate done:NO downloadURL:nil username:nil password:nil reason:@"Invalid Request"];

        }

    } else {

        [delegate done:NO downloadURL:nil username:nil password:nil reason:@"Invalid Request"];

    }

}

@end


----

//ViewController.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <IssuesPickerDelegate, IssueTableDelegate, AuthorizationDelegate> {

    Authorization *authorization;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Authorization *authorization;

----

//ViewController.m

@synthesize authorization;

-(void)done:(BOOL *)done downloadURL:(NSURL *)downloadURL username:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password reason:(NSString *)reason {

NSLog(@"Done");

if ((done == YES) && ([reason compare:@"Received Authorization"] == 0)) {


} else if ([reason compare:@"Incorrect Credentials"] == 0) {

    Login *login = [[Login alloc] init];

}

}


-(void)getAuthorization {

//this part here causes the crash

authorization = [[Authorization alloc] init];
authorization.delegate = self;

}
```

Comment: The error message says that it's crashing because of setting the delegate on a class called `ViewController`, but you're saying that the class is `Authorization`. Can you elaborate/clarify?

Comment: Please Post your code, just that we can help you.

Comment: @ParthBhatt I'm looking at that link. Give me one second guys!

Comment: @JackHumphries: Did you properly create `@property` and `@synthesize` i.e property and synthesize your delegate declaration? If this doesn't help you. Please post your code, so that we can better help you.

Comment: @JackHumphries: Did you refer to my link?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360372/fail-in-assigning-self-delegate-it-produce-unrecognized-selector-sent

Comment: What is Authorization subclassing ? It seems that your class is subclassing UIViewController. Your class doesn't implement a delegate method. What are you trying to do exactly ? this is a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to UIViewController class reference

Comment: @ParthBhatt I posted my code. Thanks.

Comment: @Parth: `@required` is the default if no directive is present explicitly.

Comment: @ParthBhatt I inserted "@required" right below "@protocol AuthorizationDel...". It did not change anything. On the real device everything works as expected until the third time when it crashes and I receive the message in the log.

Comment: @lulius: Ok sorry, my bad. I forgot that.

Comment: @JackHumphries: I don't think there is any problem in this part of the code. Please post code for Authorization Class

Comment: @ParthBhatt I just posted all of it.

Comment: @JackHumphries: Put the break point at `init` method of Authorization class and debug line by line, especially for third time because that is when it really crashes, right?

Comment: I will suggest you to rename your id<AuthorizationDelegate> delegate to id<AuthorizationDelegate> authDelegate to just avoid ambiguity and clear understanding.

Comment: could you post the output of the debugger performing : po 0xde2e6e0

Comment: @elio.d Sure, uh, how exactly would I do that? I posted the log above, if that's the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: I just sent this as a TSI to Apple. I need to access this authorization code from multiple places within the app, so putting it in ViewController (therefore eliminating delegate) won't do. I'll let you know what the problem is as soon as we work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to return a value from `-(id)init`. I am returning `self`. My new `-(id)init` code is below.

```
-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"exampleID" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *passPhrase = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];         

    // Start request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.website.com/authorization.php"]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:passPhrase forKey:@"passphrase"];
    [request setPostValue:@"YES" forKey:@"receivingAuthorization"];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    return self;

}
```